# Sorting random array of elements in console.log with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, random, console

This is probably a basic question but its the kind of thing that I almost never use... and I have to do it to help a teamate in class.

I need to write a jquery script to sort in console.log all these numbers randomly each time I refresh the browser.

var numbers = [523,3452,334,31,57,5346];

Is it clear enough? Anybody can help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbers = [523,3452,334,31,57,5346];
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(numbers);
```

Try to use `sort()` from `es6`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Thanks, but it has to change the sequence each time we refresh the browser